# Трудное слово "а капелла"

Tags: орфография, морфология

А капелла - пение без инструментального сопровождения.
Во-первых, никак не могу запомнить, как правильно пишется это слово. Мне всегда хочется написать его слитно по аналогии с "априори". Но еще очень интересно: а какая это, собственно, часть речи? "Петь а капелла" - петь как? Или петь что? Я склоняюсь к тому, что это такое странное прилагательное, но утверждать не берусь, хочу услышать мнение специалистов.
Итак: как правильно пишется - "Акапелла" или "А капелла" и какая это часть речи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: А капелла ***неиз***.(муз).Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин. Может быть и наречием и существительным.
Петь а капелла ( петь как? ) т.е. без музыкального сопровождения.Но: ***А капе́лла***  — пение (как правило, хоровое) без инструментального сопровождения. Здесь существительное.